# IIS 7 Dynamic Compression is not consistently compressing responses

Tags: wcf, iis-7, http-compression

I have got Dynamic Compression enabled on IIS for all content types.

Requests to my WCF service are sending the following header:

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

And responses from IIS are nearly always being compressed and show the following content in the header:

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding

However, when the response to a request is large e.g. 14Mb, I'm finding that the the request is not being compressed. The request header includes the accept-encoding statement and the content type is the same, however, the response does not include the content-encoding or vary headers.

Is there a limit to the size of IIS request that can be compressed? My application is working correctly but performing slowly when the responses are big as a result of this problem.

Comment: Take a look at http://forums.iis.net/t/1199034.aspx?IIS+7+5+HTTP+Dynamic+Compression+file+size there are a few things you can check to see if you hitting size limitations

Comment: Thanks for the link. I seem to be hitting the same maximum limit as the author. If my WCF response is <4mb, it is compressed and if it is >4Mb, the compression is not happening.

Unfortunately, the link doesn't provide a solution to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the second and 3rd post, they show you how to increased the maxAllowedContentLength and the 3rd post shows you how to increase the max AppPool disk space. Or are you saying you tried increasing both of these but still have the same problem?